# Qual é a diferença entre setSize e setBounds?

Tags: java, swing

Qual é a diferença no Swing do Java, entre os métodos `setSize` e `setBounds`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estes dois códigos são praticamente equivalentes:

```java
int x = ..., y = ..., w = ..., h = ...;
JComponent x = ...;
x.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
```

```java
int x = ..., y = ..., w = ..., h = ...;
JComponent x = ...;
x.setSize(w, h);
x.setLocation(x, y);
```

Ou seja, o `setBounds` é uma forma de definir a posição e o tamanho ao mesmo tempo, enquanto que o `setSize` define apenas o tamanho e o `setLocation` apenas a posição.